# How can I take the data to Array ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I fetch data from an API and data takes successfully but there is a problem when I determine the data to an array.
Array doesn't assign the data.

```
 const [Profile,setProfile]=useState([]);//I created array state here
  const [username,setUsername]=useState('');
  const [password,setPassword]=useState('');
  const [logout,setLogout]=useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(Profile);
    }
  }, [Profile.length])
  const login = () => {
    
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    var raw = JSON.stringify({username, password});
    
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("http://localhost/scheduleapp/api/personals/login", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(response =>{setProfile(response) ;console.log(response); localStorage.setItem('Logged',response)})//here response is seen console and setted to local storage with success but setstate doesnt work
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      
      
  }
```

As I say `setstate` doesn't set data to array

Comment: Note that setting the "Access-Control-Allow-*" headers on your request does absolutely nothing. Those headers only have affect on responses to browsers. As far as your problem goes, in your second `then`, `response` is a string. If you want an array, you probably want to use `response.json()` in the first `then`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried all but still same.. Thanks for first advice

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what `response` is in the second `then`. Also show how you are determining whether data is getting set by `setProfile`. Remember that that is an asynchronous method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an array to your state. First you can give that state an empty array as an initial value.
Example -
const [ data, setdata] = useState([])
After that you can destructor your response and assign them one by one to the array like this

setdata(... response)

Make sure the response is an array.

Comment: The question shows that the OP is already using `useState([])`. Please read the question and make sure you understand the question and the problem before answering with general advice which can apply to any question. Stack Overflow exists to provide specific answers to specific questions, not the same old tired answers to every question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the profile state, you need to renamed it to 'profile' instead of 'Profile' because React assuming is a component for the capitalization, that's why it never assigns the value to the state.

for Example:

```
const [profile,setProfile]=useState([]);
```

instead of this:

```
const [Profile,setProfile]=useState([]);
```

Other important detail is how you are using the 'useEffect' for example when you are console.log the results is when the component is unmounted, to make sure you are setting the value put it outside the useEffect to see if the state is changing like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(Profile);
    }
}, [Profile.length])
```

use like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // call your function here if you want to execute when the component is mounted.
}, []);
console.log(profile);
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Change how you console.log the information like the example

Comment: It also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

use `response.json()` instead of `response.text()` and for storing the response in the localStorage use `localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: it also didnt work really this error very strange